# On the role of $\diamondsuit$

Tags: set-theory, forcing, infinite-combinatorics, axioms, continuum-hypothesis

The well-known axiom $\diamondsuit$ states that there is a sequence $\langle A_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ (a *$\diamondsuit$-sequence)* of countable sets with the  property that for any $A\subseteq\omega_1$, there is a $\delta<\omega_1$ (equivalently, stationarily many $\delta<\omega_1$) for which $A\cap\delta= A_\delta$.

$\diamondsuit$ holds in the constructible universe $L$, and implies the Continuum Hypothesis. The axiom is also a key ingredient in many constructions, and research over the past half-century has given us a good understanding of when the use of $\diamondsuit$ is necessary, in the sense that it cannot be replaced by simply assuming the Continuum Hypothesis.

There are many strengthenings of $\diamondsuit$ that have been studied and utilized in constructions, e.g. $\diamondsuit^*$, $\diamondsuit^+$, $\diamondsuit^\sharp$, and of course $V=L$).

My question is:  what are some examples of statements $\Phi$ where a strengthening of $\diamondsuit$ is known to imply $\Phi$, but it is still unknown if $\diamondsuit$ itself implies $\Phi$?  How fertile is this terrain?

Comment: Baumgartner proved that $\diamondsuit^+$ implies the existence of a club minimal Aronszajn tree. It is known that CH is not enough and it is open whether $\diamondsuit$ is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks!  What's the reference?

Comment: Baumgartner's result appears in "Order types of real numbers and other uncountable orderings" (MR0661296) and cited also in Moore's paper MR2369944 in which the consistency of CH + no club-minimal Aronszajn trees is proved. Later in Soukup's paper MR4013972, Soukup shows that it is possible to get CH + there is a Suslin tree + no club-minimal Aronszajn trees, and states that the problem of obtaining the club-minimal Aronszajn tree just from diamond is still open.

Comment: There are various applications of strong diamond principles to the normal vs. collectionwise Hausdorff problem. For example, Shelah proved that under $\Diamond^*$ every normal first-countable space is $\omega_1$-collectionwise Hausdorff. However, I don't know whether the $*$ can be dropped. Paul Szeptycki might know.