# $\Sigma^2_2$ absoluteness and $\diamondsuit$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, infinite-combinatorics, axioms, continuum-hypothesis

This question touches on recent questions concerning the [role of $\diamondsuit$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353331/on-the-role-of-diamondsuit) and [the Continuum Hypothesis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353286/sigma2-1-and-the-continuum-hypothesis).  In particular, I would like to know more information about a conjecture of Woodin on the relationship between $\Sigma^2_2$-absoluteness and $\diamondsuit$ in the presence of large cardinals.

[Quoting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108197/sets-of-reals-and-absoluteness/108200#108200) Andres Caicedo (in an answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108197/sets-of-reals-and-absoluteness)):

*Beyond $\Sigma^2_1$, there is much speculation. It is expected some strengthening of diamond will be maximal for $\Sigma^2_2$, and we will get a similar theorem, but beyond $\Sigma^2_2$ this starts to conflict with other conjectures.*

What is the current state of affairs?  Is the answer known for $\diamondsuit$ itself?

Comment: The conditional absoluteness is still conjectural.   See my new [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355395/absoluteness-and-the-scale-property-for-%ce%a02-2-or-%ce%a32-2) for a partial explanation of the current state.

Comment: Ah, it is good to know it is still not settled.  I saw an abstract for a talk in Toronto last year that claimed a counterexample existed, but couldn't track down any more information.