# Absoluteness and the scale property for $Π^2_2$ or $Σ^2_2$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

Under the diamond principle $◊$ and large cardinal axioms, which of the two pointclasses $Π^2_2$ or $Σ^2_2$ is expected to have the scale property?

Because conditional $Σ^2_2$ absoluteness under $◊$ and large cardinal axioms remains conjectural, I am fine with the answers using additional assumptions.  Some assumption like $◊$ is necessary since one can use a generic extension without the Continuum Hypothesis (CH) to 'scramble' $Δ^2_1$ sets, and with CH but without $◊$, one can still scramble $Δ^2_2$ sets.

The [scale property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(descriptive_set_theory)) is the most important uniformization-like property in descriptive set theory; it implies prewellordering and uniformization.  For important non-self-dual pointclasses in descriptive set theory, commonly either the class or its dual has the scale property, though there are exceptions.  (Under large cardinal axioms, the main exception up to $(Σ^2_1)^\text{uB}$ is if there is a gap in complexity levels during which new $(Σ^2_1)^\text{uB}$ statements do not appear; uB means universally Baire.)

Under CH and existence of an iterable model with a measurable Woodin cardinal, $Π^2_1$ has the scale property ([The length-$ω_1$ open game quantifier propagates scales](https://math.berkeley.edu/~steel/papers/scalp21.jul06.pdf)).  There, $Π^2_1$ corresponds to the game quantifier for open analytical games of length $ω_1$.  Presumably, $Π^2_1$ in $V$ also corresponds to $Σ^2_1$ in the minimal iterable inner model with a proper class of indiscernible Woodin cardinals, with that model satisfying $(Σ^2_1)^\text{uB} = Σ^2_1$.

Fine-structural models relying on the conventional comparison using $ω_1+1$ iterability (for countable elementary substructures) are limited to reals that are $Δ^2_2$ in a countable ordinal.  However, perhaps there is a maximal such model, with the model able to compute $Σ^2_2$ truth (without being $Σ^2_2$ correct).  For comparison, $L$ is $Σ^1_2$ correct and only has reals that are $Δ^1_2$ in a countable ordinal.

Hugh Woodin has conjectured that the transition beyond $Δ^2_2$ occurs around supercompact up to a measurable.  He identified an obstruction that prevents certain models (that add extenders without adding their iteration strategies) from reaching supercompact up to a measurable, and conversely, if the models he is developing ([In Search of Ultimate-L](http://nrs.harvard.edu/urn-3:HUL.InstRepos:34649600)) work out and there is no failure of iterability, the obstruction does not occur much earlier.  I agree that the transition beyond $Δ^2_2$ is unlikely below long extenders.

Woodin also connected conditional $Σ^2_2$ absoluteness with determinacy of certain games ([Beyond $Σ^2_1$ Absoluteness](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212406.pdf)).  This connection might be helpful for getting the scale property.  Two caveats:
- The impossibility $Σ^2_2(\mathcal{I}_\text{NS})$ absoluteness under the $Ω$-conjecture has since been retracted.
- The connection might be inapplicable if say $(Σ^2_1)^\text{uB} = Π^2_2$ (in which case $Π^2_2$ would have the scale property, with $Σ^2_2$ absoluteness under $◊$ violating/transcending the $Ω$-conjecture).

**$Σ^2_2$ maximality**

Assuming a proper class of measurable Woodin cardinals:
- $Σ^2_1$ statements are absolute between all generic extensions of $V$ satisfying CH.  Moreover, under CH, for universally Baire $A$, $Σ^2_1(A)$ is universally Baire.
- $Σ^2_2$ maximality: there is a generic extension of $V$ that satisfies all $Σ^2_2$ statements that hold in some generic extension of $V$ satisfying CH ([Regular embeddings of the stationary tower and Woodin’s $Σ^2_2$ maximality theorem](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/zapletal/files/sig2maxplus.pdf)).

I think that the $Σ^2_2$ maximality gives a good approximation to the $Σ^2_2$ absoluteness with respect to the structure of $Π^2_2$ and $Σ^2_2$ sets, and in any case, despite uncertainty about what lies beyond, *I will accept the scale property in such a model as an answer*.

My guess is that if you start with a fine-structural iterable model with a proper class of measurable Woodin cardinals (caveat: iterability remains an open problem) below long extenders, then in the $Σ^2_2$ maximality extension, $Π^2_2$ equals $(Σ^2_1)^\text{uB}$ and hence has the scale property.

The fact that a $Π^2_2$ statement holds in all generic extensions of $V$ satisfying CH suggests that there is some structure to enforce it.  And a countable mouse (a fine-structural model) $M$ with a measurable Woodin cardinal $δ$ and a universally Baire iteration strategy can use a generic extension over the extender algebra $W_{δ,δ}$ to essentially conjure up an arbitrary subset $A$ of $ω_1$ in every generic extension of $V$.  $M$ can then quantify over $A$ and use "for all $A$ ..." to certify a $Π^2_2$ statement.  The stratification of $Π^2_2$ statements according to the minimal complexity of $M$ in turn likely leads to the scale property.

A good explanation of the extender algebra can be found in [The extender algebra and $Σ^2_1$-absoluteness](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.4193), but briefly, we have the following.  In every $V[G]$, every $A⊂ω_1^{V[G]}$ is $W_{δ,δ}^{M'}$-generic over some iterate $M'$ of $M$ with $δ^{M'}=ω_1^{V[G]}$ and $M'[A]∈V[G]$, hence the $Π^2_2$ certification is valid. (Informally, we get every relevant $A$, and $M'[A]∈V[G]$ ensures that $M$ cannot cheat about $A$.)  Conversely, for every forcing condition $p$ for $W_{δ,δ}$ with $p⊢δ=ω_1$, a generic set $A$ below $p^{M'}$ already exists in $V$ for an iterate $M'$ of $M$ with $δ^{M'}=ω_1$ (and we can also insert any $ω_1$ reals (or using CH, $ℝ$) into the extension), which should ensure that the quantification over $A$ is not too broad (or at least, this suffices for the $Σ^2_1$ absoluteness under CH).